# Scroll stuck on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, scroll

When I'm scrolling through my website on iPhone, it gets stuck at some point at the homepage. It gets stuck for a second and then I can scroll normally again.

I've already deleted all of my "overflow: hidden" and "overflow-x: hidden", because iOS doesn't always react well to that. I've also added  "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" and "overflow: scroll" to all the div's where it seems to be getting stuck, but nothing is helping.

Does anyone know this problem? It doesn't happen on a Samsung or any device other than iPhone..

Comment: Are you able to share some code or the url? It could be for example that an element on the background (z-index wise I mean) is scrolling until a certain point, when that's done the rest can scroll further. So this being stuck could actually be a lower element being scrolled.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I just deleted the javascript file and it has stopped.. So at least I know it's a error in the js file. I just don't know where to look for it.

Comment: Alright, great to hear it's solved in sort of a way. 
Please share the code/error if you would like some help with that.

Comment: The error must be somewhere in this:

(function($) {

 "use strict";

 
 $(window).stellar({
    responsive: true,
    parallaxBackgrounds: true,
    parallaxElements: true,
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    hideDistantElements: false,
    scrollProperty: 'scroll',
    horizontalOffset: 0,
   verticalOffset: 0
  });

  // Scrollax
  $.Scrollax();

Comment: Ok not much wrong with this. Only an extra closing   });   is missing at the end.